# If you have 2 dice, what is the probability of both landing on a product of 3?

Tags: probability, statistics

If you have 2 dice and roll them, what is the probability of both rolling a 3 and a 6?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem.  Have you done any work on it?

Comment: Let the dice be red and green. What is the probability that the red die shows a multiple of $3$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Here is a less intuitive, more straight forward approach. The $\mathbf 1$s denote where the dice are both  "products of 3".
\begin{array}{l|cccccc}
*& 1& 2& 3& 4& 5 & 6\\\hline
1& 0&0&0&0&0&0\\\hline
2& 0&0&0&0&0&0\\\hline
3&0&0&1&0&0&1\\\hline
4&0&0&0&0&0&0\\\hline
5&0&0&0&0&0&0\\\hline
6&0&0&1&0&0&1
\end{array}
What's the probability you want?

Answer (score 2):

What is the probability of *one* die, by itself, landing on a multiple of 3?

Using that, how do you find the probability of *both* dice landing on a multiple of 3?

I believe you have it within you to answer both those questions yourself.  If not, and if you make an intelligent comment, I will answer further.

Comment: Sorry I asked the problem wrong I'm just looking for how people would solve this